# nested for in loop, not working javaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

Heres my code:

```
function funky1() {
  var arr = [];
  var inp1 = $('#firstname').val();
  var inp2 = $('#secondname').val();
  var inp3 = $('#age').val();
  arr.push(inp1, inp2, inp3);
  var arr2 = [];
  var i;
  var n;

  for (i in arr) {
    for (n in i) {
      arr2.push(n)
    }
  }
  document.getElementById("sorted").innerHTML = arr2.sort();
}
```

out put is 0,0,0

html is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script language="JavaScript" src="marker.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <form>
      input1:
      <br>
      <input type="text" id="firstname">
      <br> input2:
      <br>
      <input type="text" id="secondname">
      <br> input3:
      <br>
      <input type="text" id="age">
    </form>
    <pre id="sorted">poop</pre>
    <button onclick="funky1();">click me</button>
  </body>

</html>
```

I'm expecting the output to be alphabetically ordered letters: a,b,c ect..

I'm new to JavaScript so be easy on me.

Comment: First, you really shouldn't use `for ... in` to iterate through arrays. That said, the loop variable takes on the values of the object property names, not the property values.

Comment: @Pointy Ok thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the loop you are looking for is this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i ++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
        arr2.push(arr[i][j])
    }
}
```

This gets all the strings in the first array and puts every letter into the second array, which is what you are looking for.

Your loop does not work because you are using `for in` expression to loop the array and the string letters, and that's not correct, neither for the array or the string.

Comment: ok thanks, this works. Can you explain at all why my loop does not work? This would work in java so im a bit confused thanks

Comment: Your loop does not work because you are using `for in` expression to loop the array and the string letters, and that's not correct, neither for the array or the string.

Answer (score 0):

I cant see the reason to do that, but i think the best way to write this loop is something like this:

```
function funky1(){
    var arr = [],
        np1 = $('#firstname').val(),
        inp2 = $('#secondname').val(),
        inp3 = $('#age').val();
    arr.push(inp1,inp2,inp3);

    var arr2 = [];

    for(i in arr){
       arr2.push(arr[i])
    }
    document.getElementById("sorted").innerHTML = arr2.sort();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to create a second array with the contents of the first array? If so, you may not need a nested for loop. Here is an example that may help. The first writeln shows that the items are being added to the second array. The second writeln shows the completed second array, sorted.

```js
var array1 = ["orange","apple","banana"];
var len = array1.length;
var array2 = [];
for(var x=0; x<len; x++) {
 array2.push(array1[x]);
 document.writeln(array2[x] + "<br>" );
};
document.writeln(array2.sort());
```

Answer (score -1):

First thing is first. You should *not* really be using `for ... in` but I will show you how to use it with that anyway first:

```
 for (let i in arr) { // i here is the key
    let val = arr[i];
    arr2.push(val);
  }
```

Which should then get all of your values inside your `arr2` variable.

---

If you do not want to use `for ... in` and you are using es6 you can use `for ... of`

```
for (let val of arr) {
    arr2.push(val);
}
```

---

Another option is to use a plain for loop:

```
for (let i; i < arr.length; ++i) {
    let val = arr[i];
    arr2.push(val);
}
```

---

Alternatively if you want to close one array into another you can do this:

```
let arr2 = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(arr));
```

---

## Finally

The `arr2.sort()` should now work fine as long as you now have `arr2` built correctly using one of the options above.

Comment: He needs the letters ordered, not the entire word I think

Comment: @PabloMatiasGomez The sorting that was done should work fine. it was the creation of `arr2` that was broken.

Comment: here your arr2 is having `["hello", "bye"]` and I think he wants `["h","e","l","l,"o","b","y","e"]` .. thats what I meant

Comment: I have no idea what he wants. I assume he just wants the original array in alpha order in a duplicate array (without affecting the original)